# Using smart switch to control GFCI outlet

Tags: gfci, neutral, smart-switch

I have a bunch of outdoor outlets which are all connected to a single GFCI and controlled by a standard light switch inside the house.

I recently replaced the standard light switch with a lutron caseta smart switch (which requires a neutral). I used the same neutral that connects to the GFCI to connect the smart switch. Other than that the wiring is the same as before.

Everything looked like it worked fine but ever since I did this, the GFCI seems to be tripped about once per day.

The outlets are just for some LED landscape lighting.

Did I wire this incorrectly/how can I resolve the GFCI tripping every now and then?

Edit:
The GFCI seems to trip every time I turn the smart switch OFF.

Not sure how helpful the images will be as there is a lot of other wiring for other unrelated lights/switches going through the same places.
[Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7ZDh.jpg)

Comment: Sounds like you created a loop or an imbalance on the neutral, possibly being detected on the self test, some GFCI’s complete a daily test, so if you reset it the same time it may trip the next day or a timer/ light sensor device causing the issue , I ran into similar and it was the brand of GFCI did not like an electronic switch.

Comment: @EdBeal ah thanks! It definitely is a self test GFCI. So changing it out with a non self test GFCI would resolve the problem?

Comment: Is the setup: panel->switch->GFCI/receptacle -> other receptacles? Or is it: panel -> GFCI/receptacle -> switch -> other receptacles?

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact It is panel->switch->GFCI/receptacle -> other receptacles. Except the neutral is going to the GFCI first and then from the GFCI to the switch.

I added the neutral connection from the GFCI to the new smart switch since there was no neutral before on the standard switch (obviously)

Comment: Is the neutral that you are using on the switch from "Line" or "Load" side of the GFCI?

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact it's on the line side

Comment: Can you describe the actual cable layout?  Does power go to the GFCI and that has a switch loop to the switch?  And you added a new cable to the switch to bring over the neutral?    That would be a correct way of doing it.   If it's some other arrangement please help by describing it.   If power goes first to the switch, well, then you'd have a neutral so that's not it.

Comment: Waitaminute..."Except the neutral is going to the GFCI first and then from the GFCI to the switch." If the power goes from panel -> switch, why is the neutral going to the GFCI _then_ the switch? Do you have conduit and someone got creative with the wiring?

Comment: @freeman "creative" would be one word.    Please be wrong.

Comment: @FreeMan I'm not sure why it's wired like that but the neutral wasn't needed at the light switch before so I'm guessing that is why? There is a fairly short conduit from the GFCI to where the switch is. Is this now incorrect in the current setup? Would taking the neutral directly to the smart switch and then back to the GFCI be the solution?

Comment: Can you upload pictures (without disconnecting any wires) showing how everything connects to the switch and the GFCI?

Comment: If the wiring goes panel>switch>GFCI, then there's _no reason_ for there to have _not_ been a neutral at the switch. It may not have _connected_ to the switch, but it should have been present in the box. Please do open the switch & GFCI, pull them out of their boxes **without** disconnecting any wiring and provide pics. That will _really_ help everyone determine what's going on here.

Comment: @FreeMan you're right - it's definitely going from the panel to the GFCI first - I'm just not clear what exactly happens with the wires at the GFCI (I was initially thinking the GFCI is just being bypassed and the hot wire continues over to the switch).

I will take some photos and upload when I get the chance today

Answer (score 1):

GFCIs don't like to be switched, so it makes perfect sense to put the switch on *the protected side* of the GFCI.

However, since the smart-switch is drawing its supply hot from the protected side of the GFCI, it must also draw its supply neutral from the protected side.

If it tries to take neutral from the unprotected side of the GFCI, that means it is creating a current imbalance - the switch's own hot current is coming through the GFCI but its neutral is not.  The GFCI will trip at 5 milliamps (0.6 watts) of current imbalance.   I could easily see a smart-switch NOT drawing that most of the time, but drawing it momentarily on occasion, e.g. when broadcasting to find a WiFi connection.

Answer (score 0):

Your current setup is:

- panel -> switch -> GFCI/receptacle -> other receptacles

That *should* work just fine. However, some GFCI units do not handle power cycles very well. While that should be no different from with the previous non-smart switch, there may be something different about the way the smart switch cycles. There also *shouldn't* be any effect from the switch constantly using power (a very small amount) to run its own circuitry, as long as hot & neutral are on the same side of the GFCI ("Line" or "Load").

All that being said, if practical, I would change the setup to:

- panel -> GFCI/receptacle -> switch -> other receptacles

That would let the GFCI stay on all the time, eliminating one possible source of the problem. It would also (for better or worse, depending on your usage) give you a protected-but-unswitched receptacle.

Of course, if the switch is not near the GFCI then this may not be practical. But based on the original switch not using neutral and the new switch using neutral from the GFCI, that *should* mean that everything is all in one big box and then easy enough to move the switch from Line to Load. On the other hand, if neutral is being pulled back, by itself, from the GFCI to the switch then there are likely other problems.

Comment: I think the switch controlling the GFCI is the desired function.

Comment: Your answer has just been partially invalidated by a [comment](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/236221/using-smart-switch-to-control-gfci-outlet?noredirect=1#comment454352_236221) from the OP. He's clarified that your "change to" suggestion is actually what he's got. I'd hold off until the promised pics show up before making any edits.

Comment: @FreeMan I've updated the post with some photos/more info

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to consider is that GFCI's are notoriously finicky, and become more so with age.  If you have a spare unit around, I would swap them out, and see if the problem continues.